# Search text file for values and exporting those values

Tags: powershell, search, text

I have a log file that contains references to SIDs. I want to search the log file, find any values that start with a specific pattern and export the results.

Using PowerShell, I am able to search for the value, but it returns the entire line, I'm only interested in the value.

```
Get-Content xxxservice.log | Where-Object { $_.Contains("S-1-5-21-1013323922") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`-match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operator instead of the `.Contains()` method, so you can reference matches via the [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) `$matches`:

```
Get-Content xxxservice.log |
  Where-Object { $_ -match 'S-1-5-21-1013323922[0-9-]*' } |
  ForEach-Object { $matches[0] }
```